# `memo-l` documentclass and hyperref: warning "Token not allowed in a PDF string"

Tags: hyperref, token

The code

```
\documentclass{memo-l}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\part{Part}
\end{document}
```

with `memo-l.cls` from https://www.ams.org/publications/ebooks/memoauthorpac gives

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\leavevmode@ifvmode' on input line 5.
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                \kern 5.0pt
(hyperref)                replaced by space on input line 5.
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\noindent' on input line 5.
```

Usually this warning comes from using math in a title or similar, and can be avoided using `\texorpdfstring{...}{...}`. What causes the warning here, and how can it be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class uses for the toc-entry of \part commands which hyperref can't handle.

```
\documentclass{memo-l}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\enspace{\space}\def\noindent{}}
\begin{document}
\part{Part}
\end{document}
```